# HTML text alignment in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, kotlin, textview

I have an HTML that includes 2 paragraphs:

```
<p style="text-align: center">centered text example</p>
<p style="text-align: right">alignment right text example</p>
```

I added it in my android **TextView** using `Html.fromHtml`

As a result in my view first paragraph aligned center(as expected), ***but second paragraph doesn't aligned rigth and aligned to left***.

How is it correct to set html alignment properties to make work it in android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because for some reason `Html.fromHtml` supports `start`, `center` and `end` as `text-align` values. It does not match CSS, but that's how it works.

[Proof](https://github.com/AndroidSDKSources/android-sdk-sources-for-api-level-27/blob/048d6cef38d11a9937bccc8cec517c1b149904c5/android/text/Html.java#L966)

change

```
"text-align: right"
```

to

```
"text-align: end"
```

in your inline css

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
"text-align: end"
```

instead of

```
"text-align: right"
```